# ACF Variable into Shortcode

Tags: php, wordpress, advanced-custom-fields

When placing this code in my theme file, it simply displays the inputted number of "5" (that's the form ID) on the front end. Should this code take the variable of inputted form ID and pass it into the shortcode form id?

It's worth mentioning that the 'case-study__form-id' option is located on a sub page of the options page.

```
<?php

  $form_id = the_field('case-study__form-id', 'option');
  echo do_shortcode( '[gravityform id="'.$form_id.'" title="false" description="false"]' );

?>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of `the_field`, write `get_field`.

So instead of

`$form_id = the_field('case-study__form-id', 'option');`

write

`$form_id = get_field('case-study__form-id', 'option');`

I got it from here:

https://www.advancedcustomfields.com/resources/get-values-from-an-options-page/

Comment: Yup, this is what I ended up doing. Thank you very much!